# FlexBuilder compiler bug - IWatcherSetupUtil2 et al

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm having a problem with FlashBuilder in what is clearly a compiler bug, but I can't track it down.

When my project is compiled inside FlashBuilder, I'm getting the following compiler errors:

```
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.binding]::IBindingClient
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.binding]::IWatcherSetup2
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.core]::IStateClient2
```

These errors are reported without a path or location.

My project is a flex4 project, moderately complex.  It has 6 swc projects, which are referenced within a swf project.  (The swf project is the one that's reporting the error).

The ANT build script compiles the project fine.

The problem exists on more than 1 PC.

How do I start tracking down what's causing the problem?

Comment: Fancy seeing you here Marty! I've got exactly the same intermittent problem. Very annoying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen similar errors when there is a version mismatch between a SWC and the main project.  Make sure all your libraries are compiled against the same SDK that your project is.  IF you're using frameworks or other open source libraries, I strongly recommend you get the source and re-compile.

Also check to make sure that all the projects target the same player version.

My impression is that this type of error is more likely to occur in point releases than major releases, but it seems to be very inconsistent.

[More Info](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/12/7/Flex-4-Library-Project-Type-not-found-or-not-a-compiletime-constant-Matrix3D)

Comment: Hmm  adding the playerversion to the swc's didn't help.  Recompiling all our dependent swc frameworks is gonna take a while...  Watch this space.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that problem with my project today. Turns out that one of the projects that I had was using the 3.5 sdk while the others were using 4.0. I changed the sdk for the 3.5 project to 4.0 and the error disappeared. Thanks!